# iOS - Continuously send location to a server using Xamarin

Tags: ios, gps, xamarin, server

I'm working on a app similar to [Happn](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/happn-dating-app-to-find-people/id489185828?mt=8) and Tinder. For the app to be okay, it needs to continuously send to a server the position of the user that has the app installed.

For this, I've split the problem in two parts: 1. save locally into a database all the significant location changes 2. from time to time, send to the server the stored positions

The first part it works okay, I'm saving all the positions with success. The problem is that I can't find a proper way of sending that data to the server. Is background fetch a solution? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: will it help? http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_1_introduction_to_backgrounding_in_ios/

Comment: no :( In another test of mine, I'm using only the location change event and after having more then 30 position I'm sending them to the server.  But after 4-5 hours of good working, it just stops.